# R - How to overlay the average of a set of iid RVs

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

In the code below I build a 40x1000 data frame where in each column I have the cumulative means for successive random draws from an exponential distribution with parameter lambda = 0.2.
I add an additional column to host the specific number of the "draw".
I also calculate the rowmeans as df_means.

How do I add df_means (as a black line) on top of all my simulated RVs? I don't understand ggplot well enough to do this.

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(1000,cumsum(rexp(40,lambda))/(1:40)))
df$draw <- seq(1,40)
df_means <- rowMeans(df)

Molten <- melt(df, id.vars="draw")
ggplot(Molten, aes(x = draw, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line() + theme(legend.position = "none") + geom_line(df_means)
```

How would I add plot(df_means, type="l") to my ggplot, below?

Thank you,
[image: 1000 rexp iids]

Answer (score 1):

You can make another `data.frame` with the means and ids and use that to draw the line,

```
df_means <- rowMeans(df)
means <- data.frame(id=1:40, mu=df_means)

ggplot(Molten, aes(x=draw, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  geom_line(data=means, aes(x=id, y=mu), color="black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_summary.html)

```
stat_sum_df <- function(fun, geom="crossbar", ...) {
  stat_summary(fun.data=fun, colour="red", geom=geom, width=0.2, ...)
}

k<-ggplot(Molten, aes(x = draw, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line() + theme(legend.position = "none") 
k+stat_sum_single(mean) #gives you the required plot
```

[image]